# CSS button styles

Tags: html, css, hover

I am a beginner in html and I have problem with css button styles.

[image]

I can understand .button code
please discribe me to above code that I rounded in red colour border.

Some help from anyone know about html and css

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please provide debugging details in form of a [repro] and not as an image. An image is an inappropriate and not useful substitute to provide debugging details. Other coders have to type down your code in order to help you just because you were too lazy to use copy and paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you're looking at are different kinds of [**selectors** for CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php).

They're a way of targeting different parts of your HTML.

#### First example

```css
.button span {
  ...
}
```

This is possibly the most common usage of selectors, called "decedents".
`.button span` "means" *HTML with the "button" class and has a descendant `span` element*
So it would look like this:

```css
.button span {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<button class="button">
  Button Text
</button>
<button class="button">
  Some text
  <br />
  <span>I'm Red</span>
</button>
<button>
  Some text
  <span>I'm not Red</span>
</button>
```

#### Second example

`.button span:after` uses the aforementioned descendent selector but also combines it with the "and" selector... that's the `span:after` part!

Any selectors written with a `:` before them are called "*pseudo-elements*". They can be from mouse events (such as `:hover`), or they can things like the `:before` or `:after` pseudo-elements.

```css
.button span:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">
  Button Text
</button>
<button class="button">
  <span>I'm Red when you hover on me</span>
  <br/>
  But I will never be red when you hover
</button>
<button>
  <span>I'm not Red when you hover</span>
</button>

<div class="button">
  <span>I will be red when you hover on me</span>
</div>
```

CSS can be tricky, its a big world out there!
Be sure to check out [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors) or [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php) as they have some really good [interactive examples](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/trysel.php).

Comment: Does this help answer your question? If so don't forget to upvote/accept the answer